# how to make svn repository using existing svn checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I had kept my svn code repository on ubuntu machine, but unfortunately the machine was deleted so the svn repository was also deleted. but i had already svn checkedout the code. now i created the new machine and also set up the repository, now i want to push my existing checkedout code with their commit history to the new repository

i want too create a svn repository using already checked out code from different repository with their history. for achieving this what i had tried is i had created the new repository and then tried to relocate the already checkedout code to this repository but its not working

Answer (score 1):

1. Subversion working copies do not contain version history.
2. If you lost your repository, but have a working copy, then you can recover the repository without version history. You need to

   1. Create a new empty repository.
   2. Import your project's data to the repository. Don't forget to exclude the hidden `.svn` directory from your import. E.g. move it out from your current working copy.
   3. Checkout from your new repository into the working copy. It will become connected to your new repository.

Check the procedure described at http://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#setting-up-a-local-repo.